# How to remove "position: absolute" from Angular5 component mydaterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have some problem with incorrect render of the component "mydaterangepicker". The  problem is in some styles which contains "position: absolute". If I remove it from the Chrome Dev Tools - it works fine. But I can not remove it from the styles of my component. And there are no options to correct this.
[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<my-date-range-picker
    id="datepicker"
    placeholder= "{{ 'choose_period' | translate }}"
    name="mydaterange"
    [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
  >
</my-date-range-picker>
```

And options:

```
myDateRangePickerOptions: IMyDrpOptions = {
    showClearDateRangeBtn: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    width: '100%',
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    editableDateRangeField: false,
    showSelectDateText: false
  };
```

Is there any solutions to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using the css !important operator? This will override whatever you specify.

Comment: just clobber the style in CSS, it's a one-class rule that should override easily, no !important needed, just use 2+ selector terms or an id

Comment: You could use the CSS: `.header.mydrp { position: static; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the CSS !important operator to override and specify what you want.

As @Dandavis said in comment it is not needed. But this may solve your problem.

```
.className {
     position: initial !important; // default value 
}
```

Hope this helps!